# I am getting unexplained error in encoding program

Tags: python, encoding

I am making a program that will encrypt a file through an offset factor. But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\computer science\programming\year 10\controlled assessment\code.py", line 40, in <module>
    file1.write(chr(encode))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x88' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here is the relevant bit of the code:

```
if choice == '1':
    a = open('saved.txt', 'w')
    a.close()
    file = open('sample.txt', 'r')
    file = file.read()
    thing = list(file)
    for i in range(len(thing)):
        encode = ord(thing[i])
        encode = encode + offset
        if encode > 177:
            encode = encode - 177
        print(encode)
        file1 = open('saved.txt', 'a')
        file1.write(chr(encode))
    #file1.close()
    file2 = open('saved.txt', 'r')
    print(file2.read())
    #file.close()
    #file2.close()
```

But when I make the offset factor very small for example 1 or 2 then it works.

Comment: i am not qiute sure how this question is the same as that question

Answer (score 0):

the ascii table does not go up to 177 rather it only goes up to 127.
just changhe the 177 for 127

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write binary data (text, once encrypted, is just bytes, not text anymore).

Open the file in *binary mode* and write `bytes` objects:

```
for i in range(len(thing)):
    encode = ord(thing[i])
    encode = encode + offset
    if encode > 177:
        encode = encode - 177
    print(encode)
    with open('saved.txt', 'ab') as file1:
        file1.write(bytes([encode]))
```

You'll have to do the same when *reading* your data; perhaps print out the encrypted result as hex:

```
with open('saved.txt', 'rb') as file2:
    print(file2.read().hex())
```

It'd be more efficient if you created a `bytearray()` object *first*, append to that, then write out the whole array at the end.